# xampm phpmyadmin cannot edit, delete or add database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed Xampp and I was able to start apach and mysql with `8080` port,
but the problem is when I want to log in `phpmyadmin` using this link:
`http://localhost:8080/dashboard/`

I can't login unless I changed this line in `config.inc.php`
from `['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`  to `['auth_type'] = 'config';`

and it let me login without username and password and I can't edit, delete or add new database.

for example when I try to create new databse it stuck on this message:
`(processing request)`

any help will be appreciated.

I am using windows 10

Comment: http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ should direct you to login

Comment: @connormcwood I can login but I can't edit, delete or add database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config.inc.php`, if you changed your DB username and password, make sure it's correct in these lines:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '<user>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '<password>';
```

Hope I helped! -CM